# Call multiple methods on namespace object?

Tags: php, class, namespaces

when I run the class it throws me the error "**Call to a member function pass () on null**"

```
<?php

namespace Epys\Login;

class Demo{

   function user($u){
   }

   function pass($p){
   }
}

$demo = New \Epys\Login\Demo();
$demo->user(xxx)->pass(xxx);
```

Does anyone know why it throws this error when using namespaces?

Comment: _"Not Work!!!"_ is not particularly descriptive. Could you please explain what that means?

Comment: Seems fine here (with some minor syntax and return value corrections) ~ https://3v4l.org/31mIB

Answer (score -1):

**Second class:**

```
namespace Epys\Login;

class Demo{

   function user($u){
       return $this;  // solve my problem.
   }

   function pass($p){
   }
}

$demo = New \Epys\Login\Demo();
$demo->user(xxx)->pass(xxx);
```

**return $this;** solve my problem.